# In R, how do I separate a column based on position in that column?

Tags: r

In R, I have a data frame where I have several columns where I am simply looking to separate it, and make those separations into new columns.

I have tried multuple strings and such but can't seem to figure it out

```
Ex: 
Lat 
4440046
Deg min sec
44  40   046
```

Comment: Please include an example and expected output

Comment: Using `substr`?

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyr`, you can do:

```
separate(df, latt, into = c("deg", "min", "sec"), sep = c(2, 4))

  deg min sec
1  44  40 046
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(latt = c("4440046"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```